# Label on bars in JFreeChart Bar Graph

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jfreechart

Please consider following graph :
[image]

The above bar graph is built using jfreechart. I have two questions:

1) Values (1,5,4 etc.)are printed on the top *but within* the bars.How to display these on the top *but above* the bars?

2)Each value is printed on the bars in horizontal manner. How to display them in proper vertical manner?

Thanks...

Comment: [`BarChartDemo8`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp) is an example.

Comment: @trashgod: there are lot of examples there but source code is missing.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at `ItemLabelPosition`, as explained [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/class-use/ItemLabelPosition.html).

It is a property on the `BarRenderer` for the given chart. Try experimenting with the different values for the desired result.

Comment: +1 for the central concept; more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9075240/230513).

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @Jes's helpful suggestion, you can see how [`ChartFactory.createBarChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createBarChart%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset,%20org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) uses `ItemLabelPosition` in the relevant [source code](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.829). More on the label generator parameters may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8117844/230513).