# make label in type line (x line) is vertical in jfreechart

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I have created an application that show my data in jtable into a jfreechart. The version of my jfreechart is a line chart. The screenshot is like this :

[image]

1. How to make the label in line of type is vertical, so it will look neat or orderly
2. How to make a label of value in meetings axis values ​​and axis type

This is my code

```
public class LineChartDemo1 extends ApplicationFrame {

/**
 * Creates a new demo.
 *
 * @param title the frame title.
 */
List<ReportChart> theDatas;

public LineChartDemo1(final String title, List<ReportChart> chartData) {
    super(title);

    this.theDatas = chartData;
    final CategoryDataset dataset = createDataset();
    final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
    final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 270));
    setContentPane(chartPanel);

    Main_Menu.presentase.removeAll(); // My form
    Main_Menu.presentase.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout()); // My form
    Main_Menu.presentase.add(chartPanel); // My form
}

/**
 * Creates a sample dataset.
 *
 * @return The dataset.
 */
private CategoryDataset createDataset() {


    final DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

    String algorithm1 = "Levensthein";

    String algoritma2 = "SmithWaterman";

    for (int i = 0; i < Main_Menu.jTable3.getRowCount(); i++) {

        Object fileName = Main_Menu.jTable3.getValueAt(i, 1);
        String fileNameToString = namaFile.toString();

        Object nilaiLevensthein = Main_Menu.jTable3.getValueAt(i, 2); 
        double value1 = Double.parseDouble(nilaiLevensthein.toString());

        Object nilaiSmithWaterman = Main_Menu.jTable3.getValueAt(i, 3);
        double value2 = Double.parseDouble(nilaiSmithWaterman.toString());

        dataset.addValue(value1, algoritma1, fileNameToString);
        dataset.addValue(value2, algoritma2, fileNameToString);

    }

    return dataset;

}

private JFreeChart createChart(final CategoryDataset dataset) {

    Object namaFile = Main_Menu.jTable3.getValueAt(0, 0);
    String namaFileKeString = namaFile.toString();

    // create the chart...
    final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
            "Persentase Kemiripan", // chart title
            "File-file Pembanding", // domain axis label
            namaFileKeString, // range axis label
            dataset, // data
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
            true, // include legend
            true, // tooltips
            false // urls
    );

    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

    final CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

    // customise the range axis...
    final NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
    rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
    rangeAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(true);

    final LineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (LineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
    //renderer.setDrawShapes(true);

    renderer.setSeriesStroke(
            0, new BasicStroke(
                    2.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND,
                    1.0f, new float[]{10.0f, 6.0f}, 0.0f
            )
    );
    renderer.setSeriesStroke(
            1, new BasicStroke(
                    2.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND,
                    1.0f, new float[]{6.0f, 6.0f}, 0.0f
            )
    );
    renderer.setSeriesStroke(
            2, new BasicStroke(
                    2.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND,
                    1.0f, new float[]{2.0f, 6.0f}, 0.0f
            )
    );


    return chart;
}

}
```

For the help, thank you so much.

```
edit
```

I have success to make the label in x axis line to vertical
Here is the code

```
 private JFreeChart createChart(final CategoryDataset dataset) {

    Object fileName = Main_Menu.jTable3.getValueAt(0, 0);
    String fileNameToString = fileName.toString();

    // create the chart...
    final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
            "Persentation", // chart title
            "comparingFile", // domain axis label
            fileNameToString , // range axis label
            dataset, // data
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
            true, // include legend
            true, // tooltips
            false // urls
    );


    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
    ChartFactory.setChartTheme(StandardChartTheme.createDarknessTheme());
    ChartUtilities.applyCurrentTheme(chart);

    final CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

    final LineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (LineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
    renderer.setShapesVisible(true);
    renderer.setUseFillPaint(true);
    renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);


    CategoryAxis catAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();

    catAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.DOWN_90);
    //catAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.createUpRotationLabelPositions(Math.PI / 16.0));


    renderer.setSeriesStroke(
            0, new BasicStroke(
                    2.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND,
                    1.0f, new float[]{10.0f, 6.0f}, 0.0f
            )
    );
    renderer.setSeriesStroke(
            1, new BasicStroke(
                    2.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND,
                    1.0f, new float[]{6.0f, 6.0f}, 0.0f
            )
    );
    renderer.setSeriesStroke(
            2, new BasicStroke(
                    2.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND,
                    1.0f, new float[]{2.0f, 6.0f}, 0.0f
            )
    );
    // OPTIONAL CUSTOMISATION COMPLETED.

    return chart;
}
```

Now, the point 2 still mystery for me
"How to make a label of value in meetings axis values ​​and axis type ?"

Answer (score 1):

1. Invoke `setVerticalTickLabels()` on the domain axis, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513).
2. Create a custom `XYItemLabelGenerator`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3158958/230513), or a `CategoryItemLabelGenerator`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8117844/230513).

Comment: what is the different XYLineAndShapeRendere and LineAndShapeRenderer ?

Comment: Among other differences, `LineAndShapeRenderer` is a `CategoryItemRenderer`, while `XYLineAndShapeRenderer` is an `XYItemRenderer`.

Comment: from the example, I knew this "XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);" but I am using LineAndShapeRenderer, so renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true); not work

Comment: You'll want a `CategoryItemLabelGenerator`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8117844/230513).